# Linkedin fetch feeds through API

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-plugins

I am using API V1 API, I am able to post on feeds but unable to fetch my feeds.
I am using following laravel package : https://github.com/artesaos/laravel-linkedin

To fetch feeds:

$posts = LinkedIn::get('v2/activityFeeds?q=networkShares&count=2');

I am getting following error:

array:3 [▼
  "serviceErrorCode" => 100
  "message" => "Not enough permissions to access: GET-networkShares /activityFeeds"
  "status" => 403
]

In App setting there is no such to give permissions. Below is the screenshot: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3644392/6f92b88a7d73be3545126b88d49234c6

Answer (score 0):

for the use of the V2 you need to require a partnership with linkedin.

https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs

check the box of the permissions you need (you have to conduct some research into what you need).

PS: this can take up to 1+ months before the partnership is accepted